# Marketing Cloud - adding DNS records for a subdomain

Tags: marketing-cloud, sap, sender-authentication-package

I need some help with adding values for the subdomain to assign to Marketing Cloud. It's probably very basic but I'm still getting familiar with DNS.

Using the domain sub.mycompany.com as example: in the example on the [official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_subdomain_delegation_guide.htm&type=5), only a part of subdomain is added:

[image]

But my IT says they need to be added like this:

```
sub.mycompany.com   IN    NS   ns1.exactarget.com

sub.mycompany.com   IN    NS   ns2.exactarget.com

sub.mycompany.com   IN    NS   ns3.exactarget.com

sub.mycompany.com   IN    NS   ns4.exactarget.com
```

Will this work or it has to be as shown in the documentation and some other examples I've seen?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for you, but I mostly have seen it with the full subdomain `sub.mycompany.com` and not just the prepend subdomain `sub` in the DNS's I have touched.

Comment: Thank you!

I got confused because in the documentation it seems they clearly remove "example.com" from the records. It makes sense but I wanted to make sure that's works before submitting. 

That documentation also mentions that the entries vary from provider to provider, so it's worth having that in mind indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Both options are valid, it depends on how your DNS services and records are configured. This works:

```
; Root
$ORIGIN example.com.

@           IN      NS            ns1
@           IN      NS            ns2

; delegate sub.example.com to ACME nameservers
sub         IN      NS            ns1.cdn.acme.com.
sub         IN      NS            ns2.cdn.acme.com.
```

This also works:

```
; Root
$ORIGIN example.com.

@           IN      NS            ns1
@           IN      NS            ns2

; delegate sub.example.com to ACME nameservers
sub.example.com         IN      NS            ns1.cdn.acme.com.
sub.example.com         IN      NS            ns2.cdn.acme.com.
```

For some DNS services it doesn't matter and the decision is more of a stylistic preference, for others it has to follow a certain convention based on the definition of root/glue records. The 1st option is more common....but if you have hundreds of these records with multiple delegation layers, you as a DNS admin might prefer the 2nd option.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the clarification. That seems to be the situation here and I feel confident to submit the form.